# Bots on Trilogy Sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

To save on some of the arduous editing and improve simple grammar/formatting, is there interest on allowing an "official" bot on the Trilogy sites to do some of this manual labor?

I'd think this bot would be permitted to make edits without succombing to Captcha's, checking validity of links, spelling, formatting errors, etc. The bot would only act under human intervention by marking things of interest (like Word spellcheck where you have to confirm or ignore) and a human would have to go back later and confirm. Wikipedia has such bots and they seem to work well.

Comment: There used to be one, but he got banned.

Comment: However, if you'd like, you could do it. The advantages of this job are the hatred of the whole community and plenty of bans.

Comment: @alex - now that sounds like a moderator's job.

Comment: @mmeyers: Jon Skeet is still allowed on the site <grin>

Comment: @Software Monkey: 1) Jon Skeet is an answering bot, not an editing bot. 2) If you call me mmeyers, I don't get notified. (This is the third time that's happened since the notifications were implemented.)

Comment: @Soft: mmyers is referring to the "other" bot. If you've been on SO and meta for a while you'll know who we mean (and I gotta say a 1 year ban is a little extreme, but all the relevant posts were deleted, so I don't know the full context).

Comment: Very similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12609/writing-a-tagging-bot

Comment: @Ether: Yeah I know who you mean.  He goes by a moniker that deliberately parodies Jeff these days.  Of course he always did change his name more often than most people change underwear.

Comment: @mmyers: Darn!  How did I get that wrong.  I wasn't meaning to compare Jon to Rich B, only to imply that Jon pumps out content like a bot on the mechanical equivalent of steroids.

Comment: @Software: Ah, now I see it. @Ether: He isn't banned on SO, but he's greatly curtailed his activity since his last suspension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think as programmers we could implement something starting with very basic stuff, then adding as we went.